# Show/hide drop down list based on selection of another drop down list using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

i need to display particular dropdownlist and hide other dropdownlist based on the selection made on parent dropdownlist.
for instance , i have parent dropdownlist of which selection will be made :

```
<select id="DropDownList1">
                    <option value="Schemes1">Schemes1</option>
                    <option value="Schemes2">Schemes2</option>
                    <option value="Schemes3">Schemes3</option>
                </select>
```

The other 3 list are:

```
                <p>Schemes1 List</p>
                <select id="DropDownList2">
                <option value="product1">Camera</option>
                <option value="product2">DVD</option>
                <option value="product3">AC</option>
            </select>
            <p>Schemes2 List</p>
                <select id="DropDownList3">
                <option value="product4">bat</option>
                <option value="product5">ball</option>
                <option value="product6">complete kit</option>
            </select>
            <p>Schemes3 List</p>
                <select id="DropDownList4">
                <option value="product7">laptop</option>
                <option value="product8">HD</option>
                <option value="product9">RAM</option>
            </select>
```

So if the scheme1 is selected the scheme1 list should be displayed while others should be hidden vice versa, any ideas on how to get this working using jquery

updated :

```
 $('#login').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
                });
```

dialog form have all the dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#DropDownList1").change(function(){
    indx = $("#DropDownList1 option:selected").index();
    indx +=1;
    $("#DropDownList2,#DropDownList3,#DropDownList4").each(function(){
       $(this).hide();
    });
   $("#DropDownList"+(indx+1)).show()
})
```

Comment: Can recommend sharing a class among the `select`s` and there is no need for that `each` loop as you could just hide them right away; `$("#DropDownList2,#DropDownList1,#DropDownList3").hide();` :)

Comment: i dun want to hide the parent list

Comment: @Stefan yes . you are right . I didnt want to change the html

Comment: I am doing all this on click function , therefore if the change function is not triggered , nothing works , so initially i want to show  the dropdownlist2. , updated the question

Comment: The change event should fire when you click an item

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#DropDownList1').change(function(){
    id = $(this).val().replace('Scheme',''); //get id
    $('#DropDownList2,#DropDownList3,#DropDownList4').hide();
    $('#DropDownList'+id).show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the HTML do simplify the javascript;

**HTML**

```
<select id="DropDownList1">
     <option value="DropDownList2">Schemes1</option>
     <option value="DropDownList3">Schemes2</option>
     <option value="DropDownList4">Schemes3</option>
</select>

<p>The other 3 list are:</p>

<p>Schemes1 List</p>
<select id="DropDownList2" class="toggledDropDown">
    <option value="product1">Camera</option>
    <option value="product2">DVD</option>
    <option value="product3">AC</option>
</select>

<p>Schemes2 List</p>
<select id="DropDownList3" class="toggledDropDown">
    <option value="product4">bat</option>
    <option value="product5">ball</option>
    <option value="product6">complete kit</option>
</select>

<p>Schemes3 List</p>
<select id="DropDownList4" class="toggledDropDown">
    <option value="product7">laptop</option>
    <option value="product8">HD</option>
    <option value="product9">RAM</option>
</select>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#DropDownList1').change(function() {

    // Hide all drop downs sharing the CSS class "toggledDropDown".
    $('.toggledDropDown').hide();

    // Build a selector for the selected drop down
    var selector = ('#' + $(this).val());

    // Show the selected drop down
    $(selector).show();

});
```

[**View demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BRDRY/)